# JRuleEngine Android Sample Source code

Tags: performance, rule-engine, jrules

Can you please help me to get some sample code of JRuleEngine integrated with Android Sample. I searched in Google. I couldn't get . Please share the sample if anyone have. I gone through the sample which given in JRuleEngine page which is simple java class.